# Shell - Save file with extension?

Tags: shell, applescript

The following is the code I have (and compiles), however, it saves the file without any extension. How can I save the file as a ".plist" ?

```
do shell script "echo '{ Filter = { Bundles = ( \"'" & proj & "'\" ); }; }' >> ~/Desktop/gametocheat/" & proj & " "
```

"proj" is a string. - If this looks a bit weird is because im doing it on Applescript, but is pretty much the same code as shell.

Anyone??

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after:

```
do shell script "echo '{ Filter = { Bundles = ( \"'" & proj & "'\" ); }; }' >> ~/Desktop/gametocheat/" & proj & ".plist"
```

This will append ".plist" to your `proj` variable (see the shell redirection at the end of the line).